# Amazon EC2, elastic beanstalk, need static outbound IP's

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to integrate with a service, that needs to know my IP's in advance to whitelist them, my app is hosted on EBS amazon with autoscaling.

Is this possible?

Here is what my current config file looks like.

```
Resources:
  # LB SG
  AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Generated by app"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - {CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0", IpProtocol: "tcp", FromPort: "80", ToPort: "80"}
        - {CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0", IpProtocol: "tcp", FromPort: "443", ToPort: "443"}

  # CONFIGURE LB Health Check different port

  # EB SG
  AWSEBSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Generated by app"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - {SourceSecurityGroupId: {Ref: "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}, IpProtocol: "tcp", FromPort: "80", ToPort: "80"}
        - {SourceSecurityGroupId: {Ref: "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}, IpProtocol: "tcp", FromPort: "443", ToPort: "443"}
        - {CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0", IpProtocol: "tcp", FromPort: "22", ToPort: "22"}

option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:80:
    ListenerProtocol: HTTP
    InstancePort: 80
    InstanceProtocol: HTTP
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    ListenerProtocol: TCP
    InstancePort: 443
    InstanceProtocol: TCP
```

To make this easy, can i somehow reserve a range of IP's and make EBS prefer them when launching a new instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your instances are subject to being created or destroyed dynamically, you can't depend on their IPs remaining the same, whether you use Elastic IPs or not.

The right solution is to route your outgoing traffic through a NAT. You can find more information about how to design and implement a NAT at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat.html.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question right, I think you are looking for elastic IP.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: No, elastic IP's are attached to an instance, and instances are auto scaled in this scenario

Comment: I dont know how the whitelisting works, but wouldnt having a wisely estimated number of elastic ips reserved and allocated to every autoscaled instance? Isnt that like reserving a pool of ip addresses?